# How do I allow public commenting on a video in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

On the Old Spice Facebook page, [there are videos](http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150154041670767) that permit public commenting (you don't have to be a fan or Like the page).

I can't seem to turn public commenting on for my page's videos (neither the comments nor the textarea are visible).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be something that is only whitelisted for certain companies. So it is not possible to do as a regular page maybe only as a a partner with Facebook.